# Problems connecting to MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I’ve created a database called `database_test` & I have a user named `john` and a password `hello123`. This is all from host `HOST`.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$host = "HOST"; // THIS HOST IS CORRECT. I'M JUST HIDING IT FROM GENERAL PUBLIC.
$user = "john";
$password = "hello123";
$database =  "database_test";

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

However, I'm getting error:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'john'@'HOST'
>   (using password: YES)

I’ve already set up the permissions for user “john” as shown below…

[image]

Why am I getting this error? I have the host correct, the username and password correct but it’s saying that this user does not have privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the hostname anything other than `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? If so then this is a firewall issue.

To check if the host is remotely available, you can use [`mmap`](http://nmap.org). `nmap` is a common network utility that is not installed by default on Linux machines or Mac OS X machines, but can easily be installed & run from the command line.

Just run `nmap` from the server where the code you want to use to connect to the remote host resides like so:

```
nmap [hostname or IP address] -p 3306
```

Port `3306` is the MySQL port and the output if that port is open would be:

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-05-16 18:56 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.40 seconds
```

But if it’s closed, it would be:

```
Starting Nmap 6.25 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-05-16 18:57 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000096s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.17 seconds
```

Also, you can check the `GRANTS` your user `john` has on the MySQL database server itself by running this command:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'john'@'127.0.0.1';
```

Or like this with `localhost` instead of the IP address;

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'john'@'localhost';
```

While your screenshot shows that you have granted privileges, you need to make sure they actually took.  Within MySQL you do this by setting the `GRANT` and then running, `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Past that, what I have seen is some MySQL setups don’t consider `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` to be the same even though they are. So I would recommend changing the hostname to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` and see what happens.

Comment: the hostname is an ip address like 127.0.0.1

Answer (score -1):

you need to add privileges to your user from host : HOST, execute those queries :

```
GRANT USAGE ON database_test.* TO 'john'@'HOST' IDENTIIFIED BY 'hello123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_test.* TO 'john'@'HOST' IDENTIFIED BY 'hello123';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

PS: I granted all privileges because your post shows that john can have all the privileges, otherwise you can add them one by one if needed.

Comment: yes but not from the right host which is HOST i guess.